# One org vs multi org - remedyforce?

Tags: sharing, org

We are planning on deploying remedyforce asap. It's use and components are much larger than anything else we are currently using in salesforce but only for the time being as we develop salesforce for other departments later. Its for hundreds of users..

I am wondering how people decide if apps like this go all in one org or if you should use multi org?

My current thinking is use one org, central repository and sharing of data is easiest...but I know setup/config/dev will become complicated.

Is it possible/simple to link orgs are there any benefits to this?

Answer (score 0):

Go For one org. It;s easier to maintain as you say, data is by default seperated. Apps are seperated etc.

Only be aware that accounts are shared between CRM and RF for example.. Supporting your clients might be something to look into. RF comes with a ratio 1:250 (Agent vs Client)

Clients have a Salesforce platform license and you might want to consider contacts. Please talk with a certified BMC partner or BMC services to discuss the use cases.

p.donders@infravision.com